# Batch for loop cannot set variables

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

The task is to iterate through each line in a file named alts.txt. Then I grab the line and split it at the semicolon and print out the text before the semicolon and after the semicolon.

My file looks something like this...

```
username:password
username2:password2
username3:
```

My current code is this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set file=alts.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%file%) do (
    set str=%%A
    set "username=%str::="^&REM #%
    set "pass=%str:*:=%"
    echo username=%username% pass=%pass%
)
pause
```

If someone would be kind enough to show me my error and EXACTLY how to fix the error it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this with `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @ClickRick it is a .bat file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set file=alts.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in (%file%) do (
    set "$user=%%A"
    set "$pass=%%B"
    echo username=!$user! pass=!$pass!
)
pause
```

Be careful using `%username%.` It's a system variable. You can test writing `echo %username%` in the CMD prompt. You better choose another name for the Variable like i did.